# How to generate a GUID

Tags: guid, plc

I need to generate a Guid on a PLC, this means: Build it yourself. How can I do that?
I have found a guide on [guid.one](http://guid.one/guid/make) but I still have some questions about the timestamp:

> If you can't get a UTC time, local will do but remember to change the clock sequence if the local clock is ever changed.

Anyone who knows this offset perhaps?

> Convert time stamp to bytes and insert into the GUID: 01d3bfde63b00000

How do they get that number? It says, convert them into bytes but I don't see how 2000-01-01 is that number in bytes.

Comment: Realize that the current number of seconds since 1970 is on the order of 1.5 billion.  Hence, the number of nanoseconds is 1 billion times that.  That is 1,500,000,000,000,000,000, which in hexadecimal is 14D1_120D_7B16_0000.  Not too many PLCs can do 64 bit integer arithmetic.  Endianness also matters here.

Comment: The offset was indeed not correct... My mistake